# changing the animation duration after each iteration

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass

So I have these moving animated boxes. They move from bottom to top infinitely.
After they go to the top, they start over.
I was able to vary their sizes and speed initially with some sass and their random() function.
But it looked stale as they went at the same speed every time.

so I tried using javascript to vary the duration of each box every time they animated. I did this:

```
let ignBox = document.querySelectorAll('.ign-box');
  let $rand = 0;
  ignBox.forEach(box =>{
    box.addEventListener('animationiteration', function(){

       $rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 3);
      console.log(this);
        this.style.animationDuration =  $rand + 's';
    });
  });
```

It works. But it's firing a lot of times for each item. It seems the animation-duration change fires the event right away again! So one item might have 8s then it jumps to 20s then to 5s. With JS enabled they are now jumping it's choppy.
Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/saltnpixels/pen/yqzZBb

Answer (score 0):

this is because `animationiteration` triggers on every start of new iteration, and changing the `animationDuration` actually restart the animation, so it goes into a semi-infinite loop.

One way to do it is to run the css animation for only 1 time, then on `animationend` event, change the `animationDurationand` and restart the animation again.

css:

```
.animated{
  animation: slowMoveUp 3s linear 1;
}
```

js:

```
//change box animation times to vary things up
  let ignBox = document.querySelectorAll('.ign-box');
  let $rand = 0;
  ignBox.forEach(box =>{
    box.classList.add("animated");
    box.addEventListener('animationend', function(){
      this.classList.remove("animated");
      $rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 3);
      console.log(this);
      this.style.animationDuration =  $rand + 's';
      void this.offsetWidth; // hack to reflow css animation
      this.classList.add("animated");
    });
  });
```

Credit to [this link](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) on how to restart css animation, and the hack.